# installing google-cloud using pip fails

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to install the `google-cloud` python package, and I encounter the foloowing meesage whenn the installation fails:

```
 pip install --upgrade google-cloud
    Collecting google-cloud
      Using cached google_cloud-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-dns<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_dns-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-monitoring<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_monitoring-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-error-reporting<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_error_reporting-0.23.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-bigquery<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_bigquery-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-bigtable<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_bigtable-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-runtimeconfig<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_runtimeconfig-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-pubsub<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_pubsub-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-datastore<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_datastore-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-core<0.24dev,>=0.23.1 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_core-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-resource-manager<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_resource_manager-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-vision<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_vision-0.23.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-translate<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_translate-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-logging<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_logging-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-language<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_language-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-speech<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_speech-0.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-spanner<0.24dev,>=0.23.1 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_spanner-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting google-cloud-storage<0.24dev,>=0.23.0 (from google-cloud)
      Using cached google_cloud_storage-0.23.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1<0.16dev,>=0.15.0 (from google-cloud-error-reporting<0.24dev,>=0.23.0->google-cloud)
      Using cached gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1-0.15.3.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
          File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
        AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\OFIRAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-j5a_32a2\gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1\
```

what could cause this? I installed other packages without problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I cannot comment, I will answer it here.

I had this issue once. I fixed it by doing the following:

`pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Some discussions relate this to an issue with Python 3*, and others with the version of `pip`.

If upgrading `pip` and `setuptools` does not work for you, try using Python 2.7*.

I have tested on my machine using Python 2.7.13 with pip v9.0.1.

Though this is a known issue, it has been discussed [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2990)

Comment: when updating `setuptools` I get this message:  `Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 23.0.0
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth`

Comment: @proton try running with `--ignore-installed` option.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the same thing? I tried running pip install but it gives the same namespace error. My pip (actually pip3) is unusable. I purged both it and setuptools and reinstalled them, same thing.

Comment: issue is with setuptools. I upgraded from setuptools 28.8.0 to setuptools 39.2.0 and all works well

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using python 3.6 this issue can be solved by following steps

1)  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

2)  pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore

For me it worked.

Thank you