# pip3 throws an error when trying to install tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have been installing a series of basic packages for python 3 (numpy, etc.) with pip 3 and everything was fine. Then I tried to install tensorflow-gpu and I got

```
user@computer:~$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I purged python3-pip and reinstalled it, this did not help.

EDIT: I get the same error if I simply run `pip3` in the terminal.

EDIT2: Ok, just to make things clear, I am unable to use pip3 for any task. Running `pip3 install setuptools` gives the same error. Also I did not find any solution in the supposed duplicate questions.

Comment: [Possibly related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources/10538412#10538412)

Comment: @Norrius , I don't see how they are related?

Comment: You're also getting `No module named pkg_resources` when trying to use pip. Note that I said *possibly* related, there might be no correlation after all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing google-cloud using pip fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124732/installing-google-cloud-using-pip-fails)

Comment: @phd I cannot run pip3 install --upgrade setuptools. I cannot use pip3 for anything !

Comment: Time to [reinstall `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10) and `setuptools`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

This looks as if your missing another module you could try

```
pip3 install setuptools
```